# How to assert a button's property

Tags: selenium

I am using selenium web driver and currently automating a registration form. There are various fields like username,password etc which we have to fill in the details and click on the terms and conditions check box and the account create button gets enabled.

Right now there is some issue with the java script and all my assertions for the create account button is failing. Is there any way I can work on this issue?

Comment: can you provide the stacktrace and html code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

possible solution:

apply  getAttribute()  function to the element you need. And compare data obtained with expected data to be:

```
WebElement button = driver.findElement(By.xpath(..blablblalb...));
String color= button.getAttribute("color");
//verifyinh that color is that of expected
Assert.assertTrue(color.contains("red"));
```